# NullReferenceException: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get returned null

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtMaNCC.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["MaNCC"].Value.ToString();
                txtTenNCC.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["TenNCC"].Value.ToString();
                txtDiaChi.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["DiaChi"].Value.ToString();
                txtDienThoai.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["DienThoai"].Value.ToString();
                txtNguoiDaiDien.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["NguoiDaiDien"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

And when I clicked a row in datagridview1 it stopped and gave me a Message:

> NullReferenceException: System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get returned null.

Comment: I suspect that one of your cell names is improperly typed, or doesn't exist. Did you debug the code to see which line it failed on?

Comment: I checked that, Others are ok but this data grid view is not yet. I thought   I should turn off the Visual Studio and turn it on again. Maybe system conflict???